# how to export filters used on photoshop file to script so i can reproduce

Tags: photoshop-script

I hope this is the place for this question, as is for scripting photoshop,

I have some files with filters already applied,
I need to take this files and "export" the effects, filters, levels used to a filter so I can apply this same effects to any image.

How to do this export?

Comment: Not sure what you want.  Are you after a scripted filter which does the same filter (say, Gaussian blur 3.2)  for each image the script is run on. Or do you need to work out what filters have been applied to an image and then replicate that whole process?

Comment: @GhoulFool hi, yes i need to work out what filters have been applied so I can replicate, Im now using https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js is this what I need?, know of something better? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am understanding your question in two ways. I don't know which one is correct

**1. Actions recording:**

First check this : [Photoshop Actions tutorial (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcZp2h5WXdA). Is this what you need?

[image]

Image source is from [this site](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/photoshop-actions/how-to-use-actions/) for Photoshop tutorials. Here is another useful [tutorial](http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/tutorials/actions.html) page.
 
The **Actions** panel has an option to "record" any now following actions you do to one photo and then later you can open any other photo and "replay" the saved old actions on this new image automatically. Whilst in recording mode, every option adjusted is added to the must-do list of actions. So things like Levels, Curves, Contrast, Filters etc are recorded if you use them, save the action (as **.atn**)
 Then to reuse on new image just load the action and press play it will automatically apply everything.

**2. File Format Specs:**
You may also consider the Photoshop File Format (PSD) specifications if you understand how to read bytes from a file. The bytes contain all data about a PSD file (pixel colours, effects, layers etc).

Read it at: [Photoshop File Format specifications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/)
You want to especially check these sections:
[Photoshop File Format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_72092)
and also [Layer and Mask Information Section](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_21849).